# Unight Lightmap Baking artifacts when objects close to each other

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am baking some light, there is just a simple direction light in a scene and point light both set to Baked mode. Light Scene setting on screenshot. This "island" is made of cubes area very close to each other. Cube is 1 unit and is each is 1 unit away.

Problem:
I do not know why I get this grid where these cubes meet.

I tried:
increasing "Lightmap resolution" to 80 (it improves it but grid is still there)
increasing "Lightmap padding" to 20 -> not working
increase "Direct Samples" to 128 -> not working
New UVs that have all faces separate with some margin as on picture -> some improvement bit still not working

How do I clear these artifacts and get rid of that grid?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGcjP.png)

[image]